# Shove/Chuck clothes into the luggage (or closet)

Tags: word-usage

If someone doesn't fold the clothes properly while packing and rather puts them in, in a disorganized manner, what is natural way to describe it?

> I chucked/shoved my clothes into the luggage.

And if someone simply throws his/her clothes into the closet rather than folding or hanging them, what is a natural way to describe it?

> I threw/chucked/shoved clothes into the closet.
>   Thank you:)

Comment: To me, _chuck_ implies throwing something with no care and little effort, while _shove_ implies pushing something with no care but some effort. If the closet is big and/or empty, I might chuck clothes in, but if it is already quite full, you may need to shove them in.

Comment: Chuck and shove are very informal.

Comment: @MichealHarvey is there a more common word?(a little more formal one?)

Comment: I [**bundled**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bundle) my clothes into a bag. The verb usage doesn't have to be its literal meaning, i.e. make into a parcel.